# Number of possible team combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

*The baseball team is made up of 7 girls and 8 boys. There are 9 people on the field at the same time in a baseball game. If at least four of the people on the field must be girls, how many different possible ways can the team take the field?*

So far all I've managed to try was 15**C**9, and then divided that by 3! to remove possible combinations where there are less than 4 girls. This results in a decimal answer, though.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd go case by case:  exactly $4$ girls is $\binom 74 \times \binom 85$.  Exactly $5$ girls is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there're 4 different situation about the 9-people team: 4-girl, 5-girl, 6-girl, and 7-girl. let's do it one by one. note that if there're 4 girls, there must be 5 boys.

4-girl: $C^4_7 \cdot C^5_8 = 35 \cdot 56 = 1960$

5-girl: $C^5_7 \cdot C^4_8 = 21 \cdot 70 = 1470$

6-girl: $C^6_7 \cdot C^3_8 = 7 \cdot 56 = 392$

7-girl: $C^7_7 \ cdot C^2_8 = 1 \cdot 28 = 28$

so there're $1960 + 1470 + 392 + 28 = 3850$ combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For $k=1,\dots 7$ the number of teams with *exactly* $k$ girls is:
$$\binom7{k}\binom8{9-k}$$
Do you understand why?